# Evee/Cycles Particles emission resets/blinks for no apparent reason

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, eevee-render-engine

I have a glass tetrahedron with a particle emiter inside and a few forcefields to direct particles. Can anyone explain why the emission of particles seems to be blinking or to reset randomly ? This only occurs when rendering, both in cycles and evee, but not in preview...

[image]
[image]

Comment: As of the current writing the question relies completely on downloading a file, the question should contain at minimum an explanatory [image or two](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/206515/edit)...

Comment: Could you post a link to a rendered video of the problem?

Comment: @JeffS [gifs work well](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) here...

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 There you go